# Адаптивные текстовые блоки

Tags: css, flexbox, media-queries, adaptive

У меня есть три текстовых блока, как мне сделать их адаптивными, чтобы при уменьшении экрана до определенного значения блоков становилось меньше?

Условно при ширине экрана в 1920 пикселей у меня три блока текста.
При ширине в 1440 пикселей - два блока, и при ширине в 900 пикселей - 1 блок

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте использовать media

```css
@media (max-width: 1440px) {
  .nazvznie-pervogo-blocka {
    display: none;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 900px) {
  .nazvznie-vtorogo-blocka {
    display: none;
  }
}
```